# How to query to get only rows where a change took place? (changes can go back and forth)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, partitioning

I'm working with a table that has dozens of rows per customer, each with a date and several columns representing various statuses.  I'm only interested in pulling the rows where a change took place in one particular column (specifically 0 to 1 or 1 to 0, see status column below).

I can't simply use `row_number() over (partition by customer_id, status order by date)` because the status can go back and forth between 0 and 1.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do (note that there are two different Customer IDs in this example):

**Original Table**

```
Row     CustomerID    Status    Date

1                ABC    0   3/12/2013 
2                ABC    0   3/31/2013
3                ABC    1   4/13/2013
4                ABC    1   4/15/2013
5                ABC    1   5/17/2013
6                ABC    0   6/25/2013
7                ABC    0   6/28/2013
8                XYZ    0   8/2/2013
9                XYZ    1   5/10/2013
10               XYZ    0   5/18/2013
11               XYZ    1   8/23/2013
12               XYZ    1   9/7/2013
```

**Desired Query Output**

```
Customer ID Status  Date
ABC            1    4/13/2013
ABC            0    6/25/2013
XYZ            1    5/10/2013
XYZ            0    5/18/2013
XYZ            1    8/23/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `ROW_NUMBER`.  It can be especially helpful in joining the table to itself in cases such as yours.

The following should get you what you're looking for:

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  Row, 
            CustomerID, 
            Status, 
            Date, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Row) AS N
    FROM    OriginalTable
)

SELECT  A.CustomerID, 
        A.Status,
        A.Date
FROM    CTE A
JOIN    CTE B 
    ON  A.N = B.N+1
    AND A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
WHERE   A.Status <> B.Status
ORDER BY 
        A.Row
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct b.CustomerID, b.status, min(b.date)

From customer a, customer b

where a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID and a.status <> b.status and a.date < b.date

group by b.CustomerID, b.status, a.date;

Comment: This will omit the first row.

Comment: Do you need the first row ? I can't get it from the desired output.

Comment: And if need the first row, just 'union all' the first row of every CustomerID.